# Solving Three Open Problems with a Halting Oracle

Tags: code-golf, math

You are given the functions: h1(f,*args) and h2(f,*args)

Both are methods which are already defined for you (here the asterisk indicates a variable number of arguments)

f is a function, *args is a list of parameters to be passed to that function

h1 returns a boolean value: True if the function f ever halts when called on *args and False if it doesn't (assuming the machine running it has infinite time and memory and that the interpreter/compiler for the language you're writing in knows how to handle infinite time and memory).

If f(*args) would ever make a call to h1 or h2, h1 throws an exception

h2 behaves exactly like h1 except that if f makes calls to h1, then h2 will not throw an exception

In as few characters as possible, write a program which takes no input and should output:

```
The Collatz Conjecture is {True/False}
Goldbach's Conjecture is {True/False}
The Twin Primes Conjecture is {True/False}
```

based on the validity of each of those conjectures.

Here are wikipedia links explaining each of the conjectures:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime

You may assume any big integer library in whatever language you choose to use will successfully represent arbitrary large integers. In other words, we'll assume any language/library which is capable of expressing `3**(3**10)` is also capable of expressing `3**(3**(3**10))` on a sufficiently beefy machine.

Obviously since it's impossible to run your program, please provide an explanation of how it works along with the code

Comment: This still needs an objective scoring criteria.  Also, *proving* that the pseudo-program works might be really challenging.

Comment: I said fewest characters.  It's a codegolf problem.

Comment: That is an, interesting, scoring procedure for this problem. "Solve the twin prime conjecture in the fewest number of characters."

Comment: man, what a cool question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## J, 207

```
(('The Collatz';'Goldbach''s';'The Twin Primes'),.<'Conjecture is'),.((>:^:((((-:`>:@*&3)^:(~:&1))^:_)&f)^:_ g 2)((+&2)^:(+./@1&p:@(-p:@_1&p:))^:_ f 4)(>:^:((4&p:)^:(2&~:&(-~4&p:))&f)^:_ g 3){'True':'False')
```

I chose to use `f` and `g` in place of `h1` and `h2`, as according to the bounty; two additional lines with **10** total characters prior is sufficient to switch: `f=:h1`,`g=:h2`.

And the actual logic:

#### Collatz

```
>:^:((((-:`>:@*&3)^:(~:&1))^:_)&f)^:_ g 2
```

`` ((-:`>:@*&3)^:(~:&1))^:_ `` is the meat of it; it's essentially a loop that does `while (x != 1) x = collatz(x)`. If we call that sentence `reduce`:

```
>:^:(reduce&f)^:_ g 2
```

`reduce&f` is meant to be a monadic verb (see end), where `reduce&f n` is true iff `reduce(n)` halts. The other loop-y bits, `>:^:()^:_`, are essentially an infinite loop (`>:` is increment, `^:` can be used as a conditional and an iterator) which breaks upon encountering a Collatz reduction that does not halt. Finally the `g` is called to see if the infinite loop ever terminates.

#### Goldbach

```
(+&2)^:(+./@1&p:@(-p:@_1&p:))^:_ f 4
```

The same logic, for the most part, the obvious difference being the core calculation is now `+./@1&p:@(-p:@_1&p:)`. `-p:@_1&p:` calculates the difference between a number and all the primes less than that number, `1&p:` is an `isPrime` function, and `+./` is logical OR. Hence, if the difference between a number and any prime less than that number is also a prime, then the Goldbach conjecture is satisfied, and the infinite loop continues on. Again, `f` is used in a final test of whether said infinite loop is truly infinite.

#### Twin Primes

```
>:^:((4&p:)^:(2&~:@(-~4&p:))&f)^:_ g 3
```

Same as above, excepting `(4&p:)^:(2&~:@(-~4&p:))`. `4&p:` returns the next largest prime after a given number. `-~4&p:` returns the difference between a number and the next largest prime after it. `2&~:` is `!= 2`. So the innermost loop is analogous to `while (nextPrimeAfter(p) - p != 2) p = nextPrimeAfter(p)`.

#### Notes

There may be syntactical errors, since I haven't tested with dummy `f` and `g` yet. Also, I assumed that `f` and `g` would take some sort of form that can be composed with a verb on the left and a noun on the right, which I'm not completely sure adheres to the J grammar in any way. They're inherently higher order functions, and I'm too tired to look up a proper construction as adverbs/conjunctions/what-have-you at the moment, if there even is such an appropriate construct.

I didn't really use proper string concatenation, and instead opted to leave individual strings boxed. The output (assuming all else is correct) would therefore be a 3 column table, with the left column being "The Collatz", etc., the middle column being "Conjecture is", and the right column "True"/"False".

I'm also pretty sure J doesn't convert integers to arbitrary precision by default, and the crucial prime number utility function `p:` does not have an arbitrarily large domain. On the other hand, given that J does support a standard arbitrary precision number type, I'm not sure how much effort it'd take to get this code up to par.

Comment: So, does it support arbitrary precision after all? I think the prime test is easily fixable like the APL answer.

Comment: Since I already wrote that in the bounty criteria (for CJam), I think I'll follow the rules and award the Haskell answer... But +1 from me.

Answer (score 7):

## Haskell, 242

```
p n=and[rem n r>0|r<-[2..n-1]]
c 1=1
c n|odd n=c$3*n+1|0<1=c$div n 2
s!f=putStr(s++" Conjecture is ")>>print(not$h2$all(h1.f)[4..])
main=do"The Collatz"!c;"Goldbach's"! \n->or[p$n-r|r<-[2..n-2],p r];"The Twin Primes"! \n->or[p$r+2|r<-[n..],p r]
```

because in Haskell variables can contain not only values, but computations (this is called laziness) I let myself make `h1, h2` take a single argument and return weather or not it's evaluation will halt.

somewhat ungolfed code:

```
h1 = undefined
h2 = undefined

prime n=and[rem n r>0|r<-[2..n-1]]
collatz 1=1
collatz n
    |odd n=collatz (3*n+1)
    |0<1  =collatz (div n 2)
    
s!f=do
    putStr (s++" Conjecture is ")
    print$not$h2$all(h1.f)[4..]
    
main=do
    "The Collatz"!c                                         --collatz
    "Goldbach's"! \n->or[prime (n-r)|r<-[2..n-2],prime r]   --goldbach
    "The Twin Primes"! \n->or[prime (r+2)|r<-[n..],prime r] --twin primes
```

a bit of explanation:

when `all` is applied to an infinite list, it will halt iff one of the elements of the list is `False`, due to laziness (short-circuiting, for all non-Haskell folks out there). we use this to compute the collatz conjecture and the twin primes conjecture.

`!` packages this trickery along with printing.
the result is `True` when `f` terminates on all the numbers `4..`. (this doesn't matter for the collatz conjecture or the twin primes conjecture, because we already know they are true for such small numbers).

the code for the collatz conjecture is `"The Collatz"!c`. it prints "The Collatz Conjecture is " and the result, which is weather `c` terminates on all numbers `4..`.

the code for the goldbach conjecture is `"Goldbach's"! \n->or[p$n-r|r<-[2..n-2],p r]`.
`\n->or[p$n-r|r<-[2..],p r,r<n+1]` is a function which given `n`, if it is a sum of two primes, returns `True`, but otherwise loops indefinitely. thus, if it halts for every `4..` goldbach's conjecture is true.

the code for the twin primes conjecture is `"The Twin Primes"! \n->or[p$r+2|r<-[n..],p r]`.
`\n->or[p$r+2|r<-[n..],p r]` is a function which given `n`, if there are twin primes greater than `n`, returns True, but otherwise loops indefinitely. thus, if it halts for every `4..` the twin prime conjecture is true.

Comment: Would you mind posting an ungolfed version of this as well? (with proper spacing and some type signatures)
I didn't know you could put the bars all on one line like you did for c

Comment: Shouldn't the primality tester go from [2..n-1]? (otherwise everything's composite)

Comment: oh, also, does p test for primality or compositeness?

Comment: I like the natural extension to haskell: h1 determines whether the evaluation of this thunk will halt, or better yet, h1 returns True for all computations that are not \_|\_ where it returns False (unless the computation uses h1 in which case the result itself is \_|\_).

Comment: @dspyz hmm. that's nice. but that would allow us to abuse the fact that exceptions are bottoms, and that h1 throws exceptions when it is improperly used... I wonder how useful would that actually be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19721/discussion-between-dspyz-and-proud-haskeller).

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure prime should be: prime n=and[rem n r>0|r<-[2..n-1]]

Comment: @dspyz I had it my golfed  code but forgot to update

Comment: I went ahead and fixed it myself, I hope you don't mind

Answer (score 3):

### APL (234)

It's obviously untested, but the logic seems sound. Printing commands are all included, the output is `104` characters and the actual logic is `130`.

```
Z←' Conjecture is '∘,¨'True' 'False'
⎕←'The Collatz',Z[1+{~{1=⍵:⍬⋄2|⍵:∇1+3×⍵⋄∇⍵÷2}h1⍵:⍬⋄∇⍵+1}h2 1]
⎕←'Goldbach''s',Z[1+{~⍵∊∘.+⍨N/⍨~N∊∘.×⍨N←1+⍳⍵:⍬⋄∇⍵+2}h1 2]
⎕←'The Twin Primes',Z[1+{~(T←{∧/{2=+/(⌈=⌊)⍵÷⍳⍵}¨N←⍵+1:N⋄∇N})h1⍵:⍬⋄∇T⍵}h2 4 2]
```

Ungolfed:

```
⍝ Environment assumptions: ⎕IO=1 ⎕ML=1
⍝ I've also assumed h1 and h2 are APL operators
⍝ i.e. x F y = f(x,y); x (F h1) y = h1(F,x,y)

⍝ 'Conjecture is True', 'Conjecture is False'
Z←' Conjecture is '∘,¨'True' 'False'

⍝⍝⍝ Collatz Conjecture
⍝ halts iff 1 is reached from given ⍵
collatzLoop←{
   1=⍵:⍬       ⍝ ⍵=1: halt
   2|⍵:∇1+3×⍵  ⍝ ⍵ uneven: loop with new val
   ∇⍵÷2        ⍝ ⍵ even: loop with new val
}

⍝ halts iff 1 is *not* reached from a value ≥ ⍵ (collatz false)
collatzHalt←{~collatzLoop h1 ⍵:⍬⋄∇⍵+1}

⍝ does it halt?
⎕←'The Collatz',Z[1+ collatzHalt h2 1]


⍝⍝⍝ Goldbach's Conjecture

⍝ Can ⍵ be expressed as a sum of two primes?
sumprimes←{
    N←1+⍳⍵         ⍝ N=[2..⍵+1]
    P←(~N∊N∘.×N)/N ⍝ P=primes up to ⍵+1×⍵+1
    ⍵∊P∘.+P        ⍝ can two P be summed to ⍵?
}

⍝ halts iff Goldbach is false
goldbachHalt←{
    ~sumprimes ⍵:⍬ ⍝ not a sum of primes: halt
    ∇⍵+2           ⍝ try next even number
}

⍝ does it halt?
⎕←'Goldbach''s',Z[1+ goldbachHalt h1 2]

⍝⍝⍝ Twin Primes

⍝ is it a prime?
isPrime←{
   2=+/(⌊=⌈)⍵÷⍳⍵    ⍝ ⍵ is a prime if ⍵ is divisible by exactly two
                   ⍝ numbers in [1..⍵] (i.e. 1 and ⍵)
}

⍝ find next twin
nextTwin←{
   N←⍵+1            ⍝ next possible twin
   ∧/ isPrime¨ N:N  ⍝ return it if twin
   ∇N               ⍝ not a twin, search on
}       

⍝ halts iff no next twin for ⍵
twinPrimeHalt←{
   ~nextTwin h1 ⍵: ⍬  ⍝ if no next twin for ⍵, halt
   ∇nextTwin ⍵        ⍝ otherwise try next twin
}

⍝ does it halt?
⎕←'The Twin Primes',Z[1+ twinPrimeHalt h2 4 2]
```

Comment: But does APL support big integers?

Comment: @user23013: In theory, APL's number format is an arbitrary-precision float, thus, in theory it can store any number. Of course, in practice, there is a limit, but it is implementation-dependent, and the question says to assume it can handle numbers of arbitrary size.

Comment: The question says only *big* integers can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: @user23013: it only has the one number type

Comment: Big integers usually means arbitrary precision integers. As clarified in the question, it should be able to express `3**(3**10)` (`3*3*10` in APL), which gives a DOMAIN ERROR in tryapl.org.